# Print azure cosmos db container

Tags: python, json, azure, dictionary

I am using azure cosmos db in python and have trouble printing data the way i want.

My container:

```
 {
        "id": "first",
        "lexicon": {
            "Eqt": "UNKN",
             "PN": "abvcfgg",
        },
        "location": {
            "Region": "China",
            "Country": "China"
         }
}
```

Python code:

```
for item in list(results):
    print(results)
```

The output is:

```
{'id': 'test', 'lexicon': {'Eqt': 'UNKN', 'PN': 'abvcfgg'}, "location": { "Region": "China",         
"Country": "China"}
```

The way output I want is:

```
id: test 
Lexicon: 
Eqt: UNKN
PN: abvcfgg
location
Region: China         
Country: China
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python output tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, but work only with dict nested one times.

```py
test = [{
        "id": "first",
        "lexicon": {
            "Eqt": "UNKN",
             "PN": "abvcfgg",
        },
        "location": {
            "Region": "China",
            "Country": "China"
         }
}]

def pretyprint(elements):
    for key, values in elements.items():
        if isinstance(values, dict):
            print(f"{key} :")
            for k, v in values.items():
                print(f"    {k} : {v}")
        else:
             print(f"{key} : {values}")


for row in test:
    pretyprint(row)
```